# Formulário Dinâmico com Flask

Tags: python, aplicação-web, sqlite, flask

Olá, eu estou criando um site que consiste em um professor criar um questionário e enviar para que os alunos respondam, porém, não estou conseguindo achar uma maneira de fazer com que o professor coloque quantas perguntas ele quiser.
No momento o questionário criado é totalmente estático, com apenas 5 questões de múltipla escolha

Como esta definido os campos em flask:

```
class NewForm(FlaskForm):
title = StringField("title", validators=[InputRequired()])
description = StringField("description", widget=TextArea(), validators=[InputRequired()])

q1desc = StringField("q1desc", widget=TextArea(), validators=[InputRequired()])
q2desc = StringField("q2desc", widget=TextArea(), validators=[InputRequired()])
q3desc = StringField("q3desc", widget=TextArea(), validators=[InputRequired()])
q4desc = StringField("q4desc", widget=TextArea(), validators=[InputRequired()])
q5desc = StringField("q5desc", widget=TextArea(), validators=[InputRequired()])
op11 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op12 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op13 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op14 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op21 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op22 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op23 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op24 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op31 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op32 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op33 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op34 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op41 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op42 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op43 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op44 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op51 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op52 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op53 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
op54 = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
```

Como esta definida a tabela SQLite (omiti o init pra nao ficar muito grande):

```
class Questionario(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "questionario"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
titulo = db.Column(db.String)
descricao = db.Column(db.String)
tentativas = db.Column(db.Integer)
desc1 = db.Column(db.String)
resp1 = db.Column(db.Integer)
desc2 = db.Column(db.String)
resp2 = db.Column(db.Integer)
desc3 = db.Column(db.String)
resp3 = db.Column(db.Integer)
desc4 = db.Column(db.String)
resp4 = db.Column(db.Integer)
desc5 = db.Column(db.String)
resp5 = db.Column(db.Integer)
op11 = db.Column(db.String)
op12 = db.Column(db.String)
op13 = db.Column(db.String)
op14 = db.Column(db.String)
op21 = db.Column(db.String)
op22 = db.Column(db.String)
op23 = db.Column(db.String)
op24 = db.Column(db.String)
op31 = db.Column(db.String)
op32 = db.Column(db.String)
op33 = db.Column(db.String)
op34 = db.Column(db.String)
op41 = db.Column(db.String)
op42 = db.Column(db.String)
op43 = db.Column(db.String)
op44 = db.Column(db.String)
op51 = db.Column(db.String)
op52 = db.Column(db.String)
op53 = db.Column(db.String)
op54 = db.Column(db.String)
```

[Código completo no GitHub](https://github.com/AndersonVanzo/gradesflask)

A questão é: **Como faço para criar novos campos de acordo com a quantidade que o professor quiser? E como adiciono novos campos a tabela do banco de dados(SQLite)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Por enquanto essa resposta está incompleta, abrange somente o problema da definição do formulário, faltando como renderizar o HTML e o mapeamento do banco de dados.*

Para o formulário, poderia fazer algo com `FieldList` com `FormField` ([documentação](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.FieldList)):

```
class Pergunta(Form):
    a = StringField("op11", validators=[InputRequired()])
    b = StringField("op12", validators=[InputRequired()])
    c = StringField("op13", validators=[InputRequired()])
    d = StringField("op14", validators=[InputRequired()])

class Prova(Form):
    perguntas = FieldList(FormField(Pergunta))
```